# Where is java saving files on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

so I have this problem:

I need to know where is Java saving the files when you create them with new, like this `File file = new File ("file.txt");` on Linux?

Comment: It depends on the working directory of the process, as for any language

Comment: @fge I think Evgeniy is correct

Comment: `File file = new File ("file.txt");`  You really *shouldn't* be doing that.  Are you attempting to read this file, or write to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is actually being created by additional code (as Evgeniy mentioned), you could try checking to see if your current working directory isn't what you expect it to be. To find that directory you could try:

```
String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir"));
System.out.println("Current working directory: " + cwd);
```

or just

```
System.out.println ("Path to file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

To see where it should end up.

Answer (score 2):

Linux on not `File file = new File ("file.txt")` does not create a file on the file system. File is just a file path holder. You need to call `file.createNewFile` to create a file. Relative paths like `file.txt` are resolved against the current user directory, typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked

Answer (score 0):

same place like in Windows: in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

Your mentioned code doesn't create new file physically on drive, but logically yes. If you alter the code to create a new file like file.createNewFile then the directory where you executed the code, a file would be created there.